# Merge changes using vimdiff

Tags: vim, diff

In  my case, I have two files file1 and file2. Using vimdiff, I want to merge the changes as follows:

1. In first difference, place line from file1 above line from file2. It means difference such as `Listing 2` in file2 and `List 2` should be `List 2` followed by `Listing 2` in the merged file.
2. Reverse case in another change.

Snapshot is shown below.

[image]

How can we achieve this using vimdiff?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52759/184487

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can switch back and forth between the two windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>. You can copy from one window do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, and then paste into the other. As you resolve differences, the highlights will change, and disappear.

Take a look at this [video](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/).

Comment: Is there any hack using a third file? It means, for multiple lines, I need to copy and paste multiple lines.

Comment: You can copy and paste multiple lines too. Or use the diffput and diffget commands in VI. I just find it easier to just copy and paste what I need.

Comment: Vim (which is the program the vimdiff command runs) is definitely a merge tool. In fact it's used by tons of programmers to perform three way merges with git.

Answer (score 211):

You can use the following basic commands to merge:

- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> - Get changes from other window into the current window.
- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> - Put the changes from current window into the other window.
- <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> - Jump to the next change.
- <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> - Jump to the previous change.
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> - Open folded lines.
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> - Close folded lines.
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> - Unfold both files completely.
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> - Fold both files completely.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> - change window.
- `:only | wq` - quit other windows, write and quit.

### Quirks to watch for

- Both <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> work if you are on a block of change (or just one line under a single line of change) in Normal mode, but not in Visual mode.
- The undo command will only work in the buffer that was changed, so if you use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> and change your mind, you need to switch to the other buffer to undo.
- `:diffupdate` will re-scan the files for changes (Vim can get confused, and show bogus stuff).

### Visual mode and finer grained control

When selecting lines of text in Visual mode, you must use the normal commands:

- `:'<,'>diffget` and
- `:'<,'>diffput`.

For example:

1. Enter Visual mode and mark some text/lines.
2. Then type `:diffput` to push the selected lines to the other file or `:diffget` to get the selected lines from the other file.

To belabor the point: This means that if there is a block of changes consisting of multiple lines, then selecting a subset of lines and issueing `:diffput` will only apply those changes in the other buffer.

(`:diffget` and `:diffput` also accept ranges, see `:h copy-diffs` for more.)

### Compare two buffers inside Vim

If you load up two files in splits (`:vs` or `:sp`), you can do `:diffthis` on each window and achieve a diff of files that were already loaded in buffers.

`:diffoff` can be used to turn off the diff mode.

[This Vimcasts post and video](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/) show this in practice.

### How to apply all changes between buffers

0. Make sure that all participating buffers are in diff mode (see `:h start-vimdiff`)
1. a. Get changes from a buffer to the current one:
   `:%diffget <buffer-number>`
2. b. Put all changes from current buffer into another:
   `:%diffput <buffer-number>`

(`:%` is a range to select the entire file; see `:h :%`. `:ls` will show currently opened buffers.)

Comment: `:diffu[pdate]` will refresh changes and folds. vim gets easily confused while merging.

Comment: For full documentation run `:help diff` or `:help vimdiff`

Comment: `do` and `dp` blowed my mind. Did not know it is so easy to use vimdiff!!!

Comment: `do` and `dp` commands can also be used with three or more diff buffers. Just pass the buffer number before the command, e.g. `2do` and `3dp`

Answer (score 19):

You can just switch between the windows and copy and paste to resolve the differences, as @David W. suggests in his answer, but Vim also has dedicated `:diffput` and `:diffget` commands to simplify this. With these (or the corresponding normal mode `do` and `dp` commands), you don't have to switch between windows, and the range defaults to the current change.

If you need to *add* instead of overwrite with the other buffer's differences (which is a rather unusual case in a classic two-way diff), you still have to *yank* the original lines and *put* them after the `:diffget`.

After you're done in one place, you can use the `]c`, `[c` commands to jump to the next difference.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post an example for my case? It will help others also reading this question. I wish I could accept two answers.

Comment: Re-reading your description, you want to add instead of overwrite; that's rather unusual. I've extended my answer with more details.

Comment: Sometimes the diff result is not automatically updated. You should include `:diffupdate` in your explanation.

Comment: Up until now, I didn't realize that `do` and `dp` are 'defaulted' to current change, thanks for pointing it out! [Official docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#copy-diffs) mention it as well: "_When no [range] is given, the diff at the cursor position or just above it is
affected._"

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following mappings to deal with three-way merges (when `conflictstyle=diff3`)

```
  nnoremap g1 :<C-U>call MergeKeepLeft()<CR>
  nnoremap g2 :<C-U>call MergeKeepBoth()<CR>
  nnoremap g3 :<C-U>call MergeKeepRight()<CR>

  function! MergeKeepLeft()
    let lastsearch = @/
    let @/ = '<<<<<<<'
    execute "normal! ?\<cr>dd"

    let @/ = '|||||||'
    execute "normal! /\<cr>V"

    let @/ = '>>>>>>>'
    execute "normal! /\<cr>d"

    let @/ = lastsearch
  endfunction

  function! MergeKeepBoth()
    let lastsearch = @/
    let @/ = '<<<<<<<'
    execute "normal! ?\<cr>dd"

    let @/ = '|||||||'
    execute "normal! /\<cr>V"

    let @/ = '======='
    execute "normal! /\<cr>d"

    let @/ = '>>>>>>>'
    execute "normal! /\<cr>dd"

    let @/ = lastsearch
  endfunction

  function! MergeKeepRight()
    let lastsearch = @/
    let @/ = '<<<<<<<'
    execute "normal! ?\<cr>V"

    let @/ = '======='
    execute "normal! /\<cr>d"

    let @/ = '>>>>>>>'
    execute "normal! /\<cr>dd"

    let @/ = lastsearch
  endfunction
```