# How to find the difference between two text files and make changes in one of them using vi?

Tags: vi

I have two terminal windows open on my desktop. I have a text file open with vi on both. Is there a way to make changes in file 2 to make it identical to file 1 wherever file 2 is not identical to file 1? The closest question to my problem is [Merge changes using vimdiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832630/merge-changes-using-vimdiff)

Answer (score 1):

If you delete text 2 and then say `cp text1 text2`, you now have 2, identical files. I don't think that's what you actually want though, you want to merge 2 files right? Then use vimdiff or another diff tool and make changes until the difference is the way you want it to be. If you type `diff text1 text2` in the terminal it will show you all the differences between the files. If you remove all of those differences then you have 2 identical files right? Then if you type `diff text1 text2` again there will be no difference. If you want 2 identical files then you should just delete one and make copy the other file.

To merge, download a merge tool or use vim and vimdiff or if it's a small set of differences you can just find them by looking for the differences using `diff` and manually making changes as needed until the difference is the way you want it to be.

Comment: What if I did not have to make file 2 identical to file 1?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have 2 files open in 2 terminals and want the the text in terminal A to be different to the text in terminal B? Then just don't type the same thing into A and B?

Comment: What I mean to ask is: how do I find the difference between text 1 and text 2, and how do I make changes in text 2 wherever changes in text 2 exist?

Comment: Like I said, you delete text 2 and then say 'cp text1 text'.

now you have 2, identical files. But I don't think that's what you want. you want to merge 2 files right? Then use vimdiff or another diff tool and make changes until the difference is the way you want it to be.

type "diff text1 text2" and see what it says are the differences. if you remove all of those differences then you have 2 identical files right? if you have 2 identical files then you might aswell just delete one and copy the other.

Comment: Could you post this comment as the answer?